# Node Microservices. Transferring a request from one server to another server

Tags: node.js, axios, microservices

I have 2 node microservices and an event bus (which links all the microservices)  running for my web app . one is basically a storage server and the other is the admin server . when a user signup the request (its content type is  **['Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ]** ) is first received by my event bus and if the request contains a profile photo as multipart/form-data the request is redirected to my storage server

[image]

but when storage server recives the request it is getting the body part as binary
[image]

and its content type is different
[image]

my storage server is working perfectly fine when I use postman and its content type will be  [image] this when I send it from postman

I am using AXIOS to redirect the request from one server to another is that is the problem ?

Comment: how is receiving it in binary a problem?, as long as no data is lost I don't see an issue. All data in the end is binary. You may want to check how you print your body at the storage server.

Comment: @RinkeshP no the body should be in multipart form so that my multer middleware in storage server can access the image

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't define `content-type` twice in `axios.post()` method. Check for example this:

```
axios.post('https://httpbin.org/post', { hello: 'world' }, {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'text/json'
  }
});
```

from https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/post-headers

Comment: well i also tried that it also gives me the same error

Comment: are you sure you want to send the whole `req` object to the second request? Maybe just `req.body`?

Comment: no i need to send the whole req  for the mutler to work properly